# AJAX request image not sending/response timeout using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have almost left no stone upturned on stackoverflow for this problem.
Basically what i am doing is sending a picture in ajax request to my **MachineLearning model** on backend which does some calculations and based on that calculation it responds me two answers yes or no. That's it. The problem is maybe the time-out or the image not sending properly. Model takes almost **6 - 8 secs** to run and generate result. 
I've used jquery's this line :

```
$("#image").attr("src")
```

to pick image from img tag it is giving me the image in string form. Maybe there is some fault or maybe not.

But my ajax request to my model at the back-end looks like this :

```
var src = $(#image).attr("src");
var form = new FormData();
form.append("file", src);
var token = localStorage.getItem('token');

var Calculate= {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/predictor",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "x-access-token": token,
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
    "Host": "xx.xxx.xxx",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data;
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(Calculate).done(function (response) {
  setTimeOut(console.log(response),8000);
});
```

Comment: You need to give us more details here. Is the back-end function being called correctly? It is returning a valid result?

Comment: Server response is bad request 400 on browser but works totally fine on Postman!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the `CORS` error which was not allowing the request on SERVER deployed on `FLASK`. Just allowed the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` on your server and it will work fine!

For requests without credentials, the literal value **`*`** can be specified, as a wildcard; the value tells browsers to allow requesting code from any origin to access the resource. Attempting to use the wildcard with credentials will result in an error.

If the server sends a response with an Access-Control-Allow-Origin value that is an explicit origin (rather than the ***** wildcard), then the response should also include a Vary response header with the value Origin — to indicate to browsers that server responses can differ based on the value of the Origin request header.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
$.ajax(Calculate).done(function (response) {
  setTimeout(function() {console.log(response);}, 8000);
});
```

Comment: Still getting  `400 (BAD REQUEST)`